# Is there any Java equivalent of PHP's http_build_query function?

Tags: java, php, http, build

I have a Map with my data and want to build a query string with it, just like I would with http_build_query on PHP. I'm not sure if this code is the best implementation of it or if I'm forgetting something?

```
public String toQueryString(Map<?, ?> data) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer();

    for (Entry<?, ?> pair : data.entrySet()) {
        queryString.append ( URLEncoder.encode ( (String) pair.getKey (), "UTF-8" ) + "=" );
        queryString.append ( URLEncoder.encode ( (String) pair.getValue (), "UTF-8" ) + "&" );
    }

    if (queryString.length () > 0) {
        queryString.deleteCharAt ( queryString.length () - 1 );
    }

    return queryString.toString ();
}
```

Comment: Is your code working? Where is the problem? What is the question?

Comment: My code works. My question was if there's any class or method that does this in a better way. I don't like to reinvent the wheel if there's something ready for it that might take a better approach on the case than my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

look at the [QueryStringBuilder](http://code.google.com/p/workingonit/source/browse/addenda/src/main/java/org/workingonit/addenda/http/QueryStringBuilder.java) class and its [test class](http://code.google.com/p/workingonit/source/browse/addenda/src/test/java/org/workingonit/addenda/http/QueryStringBuilderTest.java) :

```
private String httpBuildQuery(Map<String, String> data)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    QueryStringBuilder builder = new QueryStringBuilder();
    for (Entry<String, String> pair : data.entrySet()) {
        builder.addQueryParameter(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue());
    }
    return builder.encode("UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because that's exactly what I asked. I'm keeping my own version though since I was pretty close to it. :)

Comment: Looks nice, you should considering packaging it or submitting it to as a library.  One small quibble, the name is misleading - it's not just building a query string, it includes a path as well.

Comment: This is a broken link now.

Answer (score 3):

The true power of PHP http_build_query function is its ability to get associative array and translate it into URL string. The following code do similar thing and it allows url params to be constructed as multi level Map that include nested Map and Collections.With some more work this a support for Array can also be added.

Test methods are shown below.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.*;

 /**
 * Class: URLBuilder
 * User: Gilad Tiram
 * Date: 6/12/13
 * Time: 4:02 PM
 * <p/>
 * <p/>
 * Utility that helps to build URL String
 */
 public class URLBuilder {


/**
 * Build URL string from Map of params. Nested Map and Collection is also supported
 *
 * @param params   Map of params for constructing the URL Query String
 * @param encoding encoding type. If not set the "UTF-8" is selected by default
 * @return String of type key=value&...key=value
 * @throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
 *          if encoding isnot supported
 */
public static String httpBuildQuery(Map<String, Object> params, String encoding) {
    if (isEmpty(encoding)) {
        encoding = "UTF-8";
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append('&');
        }

        String name = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();


        if (value instanceof Map) {
            List<String> baseParam = new ArrayList<String>();
            baseParam.add(name);
            String str = buildUrlFromMap(baseParam, (Map) value, encoding);
            sb.append(str);

        } else if (value instanceof Collection) {
            List<String> baseParam = new ArrayList<String>();
            baseParam.add(name);
            String str = buildUrlFromCollection(baseParam, (Collection) value, encoding);
            sb.append(str);

        } else {
            sb.append(encodeParam(name));
            sb.append("=");
            sb.append(encodeParam(value));
        }


    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private static String buildUrlFromMap(List<String> baseParam, Map<Object, Object> map, String encoding) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String token;

    //Build string of first level - related with params of provided Map
    for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append('&');
        }

        String name = String.valueOf(entry.getKey());
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        if (value instanceof Map) {
            List<String> baseParam2 = new ArrayList<String>(baseParam);
            baseParam2.add(name);
            String str = buildUrlFromMap(baseParam2, (Map) value, encoding);
            sb.append(str);

        } else if (value instanceof List) {
            List<String> baseParam2 = new ArrayList<String>(baseParam);
            baseParam2.add(name);
            String str = buildUrlFromCollection(baseParam2, (List) value, encoding);
            sb.append(str);
        } else {
            token = getBaseParamString(baseParam) + "[" + name + "]=" + encodeParam(value);
            sb.append(token);
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

private static String buildUrlFromCollection(List<String> baseParam, Collection coll, String encoding) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String token;
    if (!(coll instanceof List)) {
        coll = new ArrayList(coll);
    }
    List arrColl = (List) coll;

    //Build string of first level - related with params of provided Map
    for (int i = 0; i < arrColl.size(); i++) {

        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append('&');
        }

        Object value = (Object) arrColl.get(i);
        if (value instanceof Map) {
            List<String> baseParam2 = new ArrayList<String>(baseParam);
            baseParam2.add(String.valueOf(i));
            String str = buildUrlFromMap(baseParam2, (Map) value, encoding);
            sb.append(str);

        } else if (value instanceof List) {
            List<String> baseParam2 = new ArrayList<String>(baseParam);
            baseParam2.add(String.valueOf(i));
            String str = buildUrlFromCollection(baseParam2, (List) value, encoding);
            sb.append(str);
        } else {
            token = getBaseParamString(baseParam) + "[" + i + "]=" + encodeParam(value);
            sb.append(token);
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}


private static String getBaseParamString(List<String> baseParam) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < baseParam.size(); i++) {
        String s = baseParam.get(i);
        if (i == 0) {
            sb.append(s);
        } else {
            sb.append("[" + s + "]");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

/**
 * Check if String is either empty or null
 *
 * @param str string to check
 * @return true if string is empty. Else return false
 */
public static boolean isEmpty(String str) {
    return str == null || str.length() == 0;
}


private static String encodeParam(Object param) {
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param), "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param));
    }
}

/* ========================================================================= */
/* Test functions                                                            */
/* ========================================================================= */


public static void main(String[] args) {
    //basicTest();
    //testWithMap();
    //testWithList();
    //testWithNestedMap();
    //testWithNestedList();
    testCompound();
}

private static void basicTest() {
    Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("a", "1");
    params.put("b", "2");
    params.put("c", "3");

    System.out.println(httpBuildQuery(params, "UTF-8"));
}

private static void testWithMap() {
    Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("a", "1");
    params.put("b", "2");

    Map<String, Object> cParams = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    cParams.put("c1", "c1val");
    cParams.put("c2", "c2val");
    params.put("c", cParams);

    System.out.println(httpBuildQuery(params, "UTF-8"));
}

private static void testWithNestedMap() {
    Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("a", "1");
    params.put("b", "2");

    Map<String, Object> cParamsLevel1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    cParamsLevel1.put("cL1-1", "cLevel1-1val");
    cParamsLevel1.put("cL1-2", "cLevel1-2val");

    Map<String, Object> cParamsLevel2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    cParamsLevel2.put("cL2-1", "cLevel2-1val");
    cParamsLevel2.put("cL2-2", "cLevel2-2val");
    cParamsLevel1.put("cL1-3", cParamsLevel2);

    params.put("c", cParamsLevel1);

    System.out.println(httpBuildQuery(params, "UTF-8"));
}


private static void testWithList() {
    Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("a", "1");
    params.put("b", "2");

    List<Object> cParams = new ArrayList<Object>();
    cParams.add("c1val");
    cParams.add("c2val");
    params.put("c", cParams);

    System.out.println(httpBuildQuery(params, "UTF-8"));
}


private static void testWithNestedList() {
    Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("a", "1");
    params.put("b", "2");

    List<Object> cParamsLevel1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
    cParamsLevel1.add("cL1-val1");
    cParamsLevel1.add("cL12-val2");

    List<Object> cParamsLevel2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
    cParamsLevel2.add("cL2-val1");
    cParamsLevel2.add("cL2-val2");
    cParamsLevel1.add(cParamsLevel2);

    params.put("c", cParamsLevel1);

    System.out.println(httpBuildQuery(params, "UTF-8"));
}


private static void testCompound() {

    Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

    //flat
    params.put("a", "1");
    params.put("b", "2");

    //Map level 1
    Map<String, Object> cParamsLevel1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    cParamsLevel1.put("cL1-1", "cLevel1-1val");
    cParamsLevel1.put("cL1-2", "cLevel1-2val");

    //Map level 2
    Map<String, Object> cParamsLevel2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    cParamsLevel2.put("cL2-1", "cLevel2-1val");
    cParamsLevel2.put("cL2-2", "cLevel2-2val");
    cParamsLevel1.put("cL1-3", cParamsLevel2);

    params.put("c", cParamsLevel1);

    //List level 1
    List<Object> dParamsLevel1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
    dParamsLevel1.add("dL1-val1");
    dParamsLevel1.add("dL12-val2");

    //List level 2
    List<Object> dParamsLevel2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
    dParamsLevel2.add("dL2-val1");
    dParamsLevel2.add("dL2-val2");
    dParamsLevel1.add(dParamsLevel2);

    params.put("d", dParamsLevel1);

    System.out.println(httpBuildQuery(params, "UTF-8"));

}

}
```

For easy test of your results append the string resulted by tests as query String of real url that point to this PHP. Example

```
http://localhost/test.php?a=1&b=2&c[cL1-1]=cLevel1-1val&c[cL1-2]=cLevel1-2val&c[cL1-3][cL2-1]=cLevel2-1val&c[cL1-3][cL2-2]=cLevel2-2val&d[0]=dL1-val1&d[1]=dL12-val2&d[2][0]=dL2-val1&d[2][1]=dL2-val2
```

```
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to check the "Accept" request header for the encodings supported by the client before forcing UTF-8 (even though it's probably the best choice).

Answer (score 1):

This should be the easiest (and most reliable) solution:

```
protected static String httpBuildQuery(List<? extends NameValuePair> parameters, String encoding) {
    return URLEncodedUtils.format(parameters, encoding).replace("*", "%2A");
}
```

Example usage:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>;
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "value"));

String queryString = httpBuildQuery(myParamList, "UTF-8");
```

Java not encoding the asterisk (`+`) while PHP does encode it `%2A` should be the only difference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK, with these caveats:

- make the parameter a `Map<String, String>` rather than casting key and value to String.
- the hardcoded encoding looks suspicious. UTF-8 is not a given, it has to match the encoding defined in the header of the HTTP request. So the code should ensure that they do - at least define it as a constant somewhere and refer to that both here and wherever the request encoding is set.

**Edit:** It seems that I was wrong about the encoding; HTTP GET parameters are not subject to an encoding header, and did not traditionally have a well-defined encoding at all. [RFC 3988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.5) does seem to mandate UTF-8, but that sounds rather brittle to me, so unless you have tight control over the server and can ensure that it does indeed use UTF-8 as well, I'd use POST requests for any data that's not in the 7bit ASCII range.

Comment: a) Fixed it, thanks.
b) Seems you're right, but I'm using restlet.org packages to do a REST request and it doesn't let you define the encoding of the request. Let's say it doesn't specify one, what would the default be? Depends on the server configuration?